# Reading the first line of a file in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, file-io, capistrano

I want to read *only* the first line of a file using Ruby in the fastest, simplest, most idiomatic way possible. What's the best approach?

(Specifically: I want to read the git commit UUID out of the REVISION file in my latest Capistrano-deployed Rails directory, and then output that to my  tag. This will let me see at an http-glance what version is deployed to my server. If there's an entirely different & better way to do this, please let me know.)

Answer (score 127, accepted):

This will read exactly one line and ensure that the file is properly closed immediately after.

```
strVar = File.open('somefile.txt') {|f| f.readline}
# or, in Ruby 1.8.7 and above: #
strVar = File.open('somefile.txt', &:readline)
puts strVar
```

Answer (score 26):

Here's a concise idiomatic way to do it that properly opens the file for reading and closes it afterwards.

```
File.open('path.txt', &:gets)
```

If you want an empty file to cause an exception use this instead.

```
File.open('path.txt', &:readline)
```

Also, here's a quick & dirty implementation of head that would work for your purposes and in many other instances where you want to read a few more lines.

```
# Reads a set number of lines from the top.
# Usage: File.head('path.txt')
class File
  def self.head(path, n = 1)
     open(path) do |f|
        lines = []
        n.times do
          line = f.gets || break
          lines << line
        end
        lines
     end
  end
end
```

Comment: Simpler implementation: `class File; def self.head(path, n = 1); foreach(path).first(n); end; end`

Comment: (6 years later....) What is happening in those first 2 examples with the symbol as the second argument to open?  I can't find any doc that explains what that's doing.  Thx for any info...

Comment: @skydvr read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14881125/what-does-to-proc-method-mean

Answer (score 7):

You can try this:

```
File.foreach('path_to_file').first
```

Comment: LocalJumpError: no block given

Comment: @klochner: Your Ruby is old. This works fine in 1.8.7 and above.

Comment: Sorry Vincent, I can't remove downvote unless you make some minor edit.

Comment: I upvoted this one because I like the "first"ness of it. Unfortunately, my Rails host (DreamHost) is only on 1.8.5, so it isn't the "correct" one for me. :-\

Comment: I like the expressiveness of "first" but I don't like the "foreach", which is misleading. I suppose the "perfect" (?) answer is to monkey-patch a File#first_line(path) method.

Answer (score 6):

How to read the first line in a ruby file:

```
commit_hash = File.open("filename.txt").first
```

Alternatively you could just do a git-log from inside your application:

```
commit_hash = `git log -1 --pretty=format:"%H"`
```

The %H tells the format to print the full commit hash. There are also modules which allow you to access your local git repo from inside a Rails app in a more ruby-ish manner although I have never used them.

Comment: .last is not working as I planned here. How do I do this for the last line?

Answer (score 5):

```
first_line = open("filename").gets
```

Comment: Will this close the file afterwards?

Comment: I also get a Rubocop Security warning for the use of `Kernal#open`: https://rubocop.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cops_security/#securityopen

Answer (score 3):

I think the jkupferman suggestion of investigating the `git --pretty` options makes the most sense, however yet another approach would be the `head` command e.g.

```
ruby -e 'puts `head -n 1 filename`'  #(backtick before `head` and after `filename`)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
first_line = File.readlines('file_path').first.chomp
```

Comment: Although it works, but won't it load the whole file in memory?

Answer (score 2):

Improving on the answer posted by @Chuck, I think it might be worthwhile to point out that if the file you are reading is empty, an EOFError exception will be thrown. Catch and ignore the exception:

```
def readit(filename)
 text = ""
 begin
   text = File.open(filename, &:readline)
 rescue EOFError
 end
 text
end
```