# Extract first line from a (possibly multiline) string

Tags: ruby

I have a String `s`, which in general (but see below) contains several `\n`, hence can be regarded as multiline string. I want to get the first line (excluding the terminating newline); but if there is no newline at all, the whole string should be returned. Example:

```
"abc\ndef" -> "abc"
"\ndef"    -> ""
"xyz"      -> "xyz"
```

My first attempt was

```
s[/.*(?=\n)/]
```

but this returns nil if there is no newline in s (because the lookahead expression does not match). I then considered

```
s[0,s.index("\n")||s.length]
```

This does work, but I need to mention the variable (`s`) three times and find this aesthetically unpleasant. Has someone an idea of how to write a concise expression which would work here?

**UPDATE**: I don't want to scan the whole string (which in general is fairly large). I need it parsed only up the the first newline character.

Comment: Maybe using the split function would work.

Comment: It would split the whole string into lines. In my case, the string is fairly long (a whole file), and I don't need it parsed completely.

Comment: `s.each_line.first.chomp`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading the first line of a file in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490138/reading-the-first-line-of-a-file-in-ruby)

Comment: You can set a limit on split to only split once.

Comment: @iGian : No. I don't have a file (i.e. a filename). I'm in a context where I happen to get passed the content of a file as a string and need to read the first line to decide what to do next.

Comment: @Tristan : Could you amend your answer to show how it is done properly? After reading the description of `split`, I tried in irb `"abc\ndef".split(/\n/,1)`, to limit the search to the first match only, but this returned the whole string and did not split at all.

Comment: @user1934428 You should put it to 2 since you want two parts and then take the first with [0].

Comment: @user1934428 the [docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/String.html#split-method) say _"If limit is 1, the entire string is returned"_. However, since you are only interested in the first line, consider using `each_line.first` as suggested by Fravadona above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `s.split("\n", 2)[0]`.
This splits the string at each newline and then takes the first element of the array. We also use the limit parameter so it only splits once.